# Custom Class Implement a Function Type

Tags: kotlin, lambda

Found this in kotlin documentation about function and lambda

```
class IntTransformer: (Int) -> Int {
    override operator fun invoke(x: Int): Int = TODO()
}

val intFunction: (Int) -> Int = IntTransformer()
```

In this [page](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#instantiating-a-function-type), it says that you can implement function type to class like an interface. How does it work? Can you give me some explanation every each part and give me an example how this is done?

From what I understand, IntTransformer expand/implement anonymous function that takes int as argument and output type, but I still didn't know how does it work...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can think of a function type sort of like an interface that has a single function named `invoke` with the parameters and return type matching its definition.

So

```
(Int) -> String
```

is very much like

```
interface Foo {
    operator fun invoke(param: Int): String
}
```

And so if a class inherits from `(Int) -> String`, you would do it in exactly the same way as you would to inherit `Foo` above. You could say the function inheritance is more versatile, because it allows your class to be passed around as a functional argument directly instead of having to get a reference to its invoke function using `::invoke`.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Okay, I'm still thinking. Somehow my understanding about function get scrambled

Comment: Inheriting from functions seems to be rarely used in practice. I've never had a need for it. I wouldn't worry about it until you have a firmer grasp of the other concepts.